# PHP header() redirect to the same page before the right one

Tags: php, http-headers, session-variables

I have an **index.php** file here:

```php
<?php

session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION['modals']);
$_SESSION['modals'] = [];

?>
```

and a **redirect.php** file here:

```
<?php

session_start();
$_SESSION['modals'][] = ['title' => "test", 'msg' => "message to show"];
header('Location: index.php', true, 301);
exit();

?>
```

As you see, these are realy basic.

The problem I encounter is that if I load the page redirect.php 2 or 3 times in row, it simply show one entry in the $_SESSION['modals'] variable, as it should. But if I load the redirect.php page several times in row, usualy 4 or more, it start buging. The $_SESSION['modals'] sometimes contain 2 entries, and sometimes 1.

**I don't understand why??**

Thanks in advance for your responses!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your session handler, there may or may not be session locking.  Additionally, browsers don't exactly wait around when they receive a `301` redirect.

I suspect your session data isn't getting saved before the second script is opening it.

Comment: I don't see why should the problem have a link with the session? Because it's correctly saved, and even/but sometimes 2 times instead of 1.
As you describe it, it shouldn't even save 1 entry in the session, however, it's not the case and even the opposite.

Comment: @FlorentBanneux Is not your entire problem that the session data is inconsistent?  This sounds exactly like two different scripts stepping on each other, to me.

Comment: you are certainly right. Do you have any simple solution for me that save an entry in a session and that redirect the user right after?

Comment: @FlorentBanneux What session handler are you using?  You could try `session_write_close()` before you redirect.

Comment: @nrad None specially! Currently using XAMPP and this is pure vanilla code.. :( Gonna check your solution soon, keep you up to date when done (idk when :p)

Comment: @FlorentBanneux Well, you're definitely using some session handler... check your PHP config.